# I need to backup or clone one remote firebird database or export it to Sql server

Tags: backup, firebird

I have a legacy system using a remote Firebird 2.5 database. I need to clone this database for backup. I do not have access to file system of the server, I can only access it with connection string.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GBAK`command to [backup remote database to local hard disk](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq62/).

> Here's the GBAK command:
>
> gbak -b -v 192.168.0.20:/dbases/mydb.fdb C:\mybackup.fbk -user
>   SYSDBA -pass 123456