# recover backup of firebird fail

Tags: backup, firebird

I previously asked how to make a backup of a Firebird database in

[I need to backup or clone one remote firebird database or export it to Sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472517/i-need-to-backup-or-clone-one-remote-firebird-database-or-export-it-to-sql-serve/43479681#43479681)

Now the backup is complete, but when I try to restore it to Firebird on my computer, I get an error.

I use this command:

```
gbak -r -p 4096 -o e:\mybackup.fbk localhost:e:\bddados.fdb -user sysdba -pas masterkey
```

The error I receive is

> gbak: ERROR:Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login. gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors

But I test my Firebird locally with this user and password and it's ok. Does the created backup database need to specify in generate command a password or do I need to use the same of the old database?

Comment: The password is given with "-pass" (double S).
Try 
    gbak -r -p 4096 -o e:\mybackup.fbk localhost:e:\bddados.fdb -user sysdba -pass masterkey

Comment: I try it now, but has new error.  gbak -r -p 4096 -o e:\mybackup.fbk localhost:e:\dados.fdb -user SYSDBA -pass masterkey
gbak: ERROR:unavailable database
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors

Comment: Thank´s, it works now!!

Comment: See also the [gbak documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gbak.html)

Comment: @ValMarinov guess you are to make your comments into the answer that Nizzola would formally accept

Comment: @Arioch 'The I did it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user` and `pas[sword]` parameters should be before the path to files

```
gbak -r -p 4096 -o -user sysdba -pas masterkey e:\mybackup.fbk localhost:e:\bddados.fdb
```

[gbak documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gbak.html)